# Jackson MismatchedInputException for Joda DateTime

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jodatime

I am attempting to deserialise a JSON object, which has Joda dateTime formats within it.

The deserialisation error is below:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `org.joda.time.DateTime` (although at least one
>   Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
>   deserialize from String value ('2019-08-02T17:33:24.000Z')at [Source:
>   (StringReader); line: 1, column: 34] (through reference chain:
>   Event$Builder["time"])

The object mapper I am using is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES;

public class Mapper {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public Mapper() {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new GuavaModule())
                .registerModule(new JodaModule())
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

With the dependencies of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And the method that tries to deserialise the JSON:

```
   try {
       Event = new Mapper()
                   .getObjectMapper()
                   .readValue(response, Event.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                fail(e);
    }
```

How can I resolve this error please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show your `Event` class and `JSON` payload?